# jQuery fadeOut() fadeIn() with html() function

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

i wanted a fade effect during the transition on my text .
but i dont know how ? did i have to put the fadeIn() inside the html methods ?
cheer

and i have to add more text because the site ask me for it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#b1").click(function(){
      $("#container")
    $("#container").html($("#page1").html());
  });
      $("#b2").click(function(){
    $("#container").html($("#page2").html());
  });
      $("#b3").click(function(){
    $("#container").html($("#page3").html());
  });
});
```

```css
li {
    display: inline
}

#page2 {
    display: none;
}

#page3 {
    display: none;
}



#page1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>NAV BAR</p>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><button id="b1">PAGE1</button></li>
                <li><button id="b2">PAGE2</button></li>
                <li><button id="b3">PAGE3</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="container"></div>
            <div id="page1">
                <p>JE SUIS LA PAGE 1</p><p>JE SUIS LA PAGE 1</p><p>JE SUIS LA PAGE 1</p><p>JE SUIS LA PAGE 1</p><p>JE SUIS LA PAGE 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="page2">
                <p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p><p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p><p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p><p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p><p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p><p>IAM THE PAGE 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="page3">
                <p>00010111011010</p><p>00010111011010</p><p>00010111011010</p><p>00010111011010</p><p>00010111011010</p><p>00010111011010</p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the element is visible you would need to hide it, or fade it out first.

All jQuery animations have complete callbacks so you can do something like.

```
$("#container").fadeOut(function(){
    /* container is now hidden so change the html and fade it back in */
    $(this).html($("#page1").html()).fadeIn();
});
```

For a quicker hide you can chain everything:

```
$("#container").hide().html($("#page1").html()).fadeIn();
```

Comment: thx you so much !
for the answer and the lesson about chaining in the same function 
i have a lot to learn on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to insert the content with jquery...

I suggest you to leave the content inside the container and make your #pages {display:none; }with css.

Then on click event call two functions:

First: hide all the #pages.

Second: use the fadeToggle () function from jquery to display your element.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a fadeIn/Out effect...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
        $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).html($("#page1").html()).fadeIn();
        });
    });
    // and so on...
});
```